# Connected a database to MySQL after connecting to Apache Web Server. One problem

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

After finally connecting, I typed 'show databases;' just to confirm that the database I created (on AWS) was connected but it doesn't pop up. Every other video I've watched doesn't seem to point out any step I may have missed. It only shows the 4 databases which I'm assuming were already there. Apologies if I'm not phrasing this question very clearly. Still a rookie self learning.

For some context, I'm on Windows and ssh through Gitbash. Also using a Red Hat instance. Tried to use an Amazon Linux 2 instance but encountered the same problem.

Here's what it shows:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Every tutorial I've seen shows '5 rows in set(0.00sec)' with the one extra row being the name of the database created earlier. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What database do you expect to be present? What commands did you run when connected to the database host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly define your database in RDS when you create your mysql. This is in `Additional configuration`. By default no custom database is created:

[image]

But you can always use [SQL to create](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-database.html) it afterwards in `mysql` console:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabasename;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. That WAS the step I missed after all :)